# customer null stripe

Tags: nodejs, stripe

estoy probando la api de stripe, para metodos de pago:
Puedo crear un metodo de pago, sin problema, utilizo el _id, para recuperar el motodo de pago, pero cuando intento recuperarlo, lo que me devuelve es

```
       function recuperar(req,res){
        var stripe = require('stripe')('sk_testxxxxxx');

        stripe.paymentMethods.retrieve(
        'pm_1FlYUDItl2uynp8LfG5zaymZ',
        function(err, paymentMethod) {
        // asynchronously called
        console.log(paymentMethod)
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send
        } else {

            res.status(200).send({paymentMethod})

        }
        }
        );

        }

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

¿Por que puede suceder esto?

Answer (score 0):

Para entender mejor el mensaje de error, podrías incluir qué aparece en los logs?

Eeste es el flujo que debieras seguir para trabajar con Payment Methods y Payment Intents: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web

Te comento de todas formas que idealmente debes utilizar tu llave privada (sk_) en el backend y la llave pública (pk_) en el frontend.